# R - Change back to regression plot after using par(mfrow) command.

Tags: r, regression

I created a linear model `fit=lm(x~y)` and then ran the `par(mfrow = c(2, 2))` command, so that now every time I run the `plot(fit)` command it will generate four diagnostic plots for the linear model: "Residuals vs Fitted", "Normal Q-Q", "Scale-Location", "Residuals vs Leverage". But now I want to simply display the y against x scatter plot using the `plot(fit)` command, yet even after I set `par(mfrow = c(1, 1))`, it still draws the four plots mentioned above, only one at a time, instead of drawing a y against x plot. How do I make it draw a simple y against x scatter plot then?

Comment: As a side note, I usually save the old values `old_par <- par(<new_value>)` then, when done plotting, `par(old_par)`.

Comment: Has someone fixed this issue? 
I also have the same question